# JFreeChart How create an areachart with an TimeLine axis

Tags: jfreechart

I want to make the example of jfreechart: XYAreaChartDemo2.java, an xyareachart but the X axis must be of timeSeries. i have tried this:

```
TimeSeriesCollection dataset1 = new TimeSeriesCollection(timeSeries);//my timeseries 
    XYSeriesCollection dataset2 = new XYSeriesCollection();  

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("titulo","Eje x","eje Y", dataset2, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true, false,false);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    XYPlot xyplot= chart.getXYPlot();
    //fondo
    xyplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    //pone la serie de time en el formato area (pero pierde el formato tiempo)
    xyplot.setDataset(dataset1);
```

but my chart is returned like a areachart with x-axis from 0 to 1.285......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) and adding instances of `RegularTimePeriod` to the data set. By default, the method [`ChartFactory. createXYAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1590) uses a `NumberAxis` for the domain. Instead, use a `DateAxis`.

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
DateAxis domain = new DateAxis("Tiempo");
plot.setDomainAxis(domain);
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a recommended solution here.

Don't limit your mind on making XYAreaChart with TimeSeries X axis. Why not **make a TimeSeries chart and render it into XYAreaChart**?

Here is how it can be done.

```
// Create TimeSeriesChart
JFreeChart localJFreeChart = createChart(createDataset()); 
// Set to be XYAreaChart
XYItemRenderer render = new XYAreaRenderer(); 
XYPlot plot = localJFreeChart.getXYPlot();
plot.setRenderer(render);
```

in which

```
private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset paramXYDataset) {
    JFreeChart localJFreeChart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Legal & General Unit Trust Prices", "Date", "Price Per Unit", paramXYDataset, true, true, false);
    // ...
    return (JFreeChart) localJFreeChart;
}
```

Full code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/ndR9rcZv).

Most of the code is from [`TimeSeriesDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html) in JFreeChart-1.0.14-demo.jar, and modified by myself to meet your requirements.

Hope this could help.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and referencing [`org.jfree.chart.demo`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/package-summary.html). See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod Thx for advice. But I didn't get it why Initial Treads is concerned here. Pls explain it to me, thx.

Comment: Just a reminder for future visitors; `JFreeChart` isn't a `JComponent`, but `ChartPanel` is.